# Can't connect to RESTful spring boot application when running as docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I am running a server machine which runs a spring-boot application, I am trying to dockerize the process. The server and client are two different PCs.

Server:

```
java -jar springdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Client:

`curl http://serverip:34256/api/test`

I'm getting the expected response

```
{
    "One": 1,
    "Two": 2,
    "Three": 3
}
```

Trying to dockerize the process, I run on the server:

`docker build -t java-image .`

`docker run -p 34256:34256 --name java-container java-image`

But now I can't connect to my application from the client:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to serverip port 34256 after 55 ms: Connection refused
```

Spring boot `application.properties`:

```
server.address=0.0.0.0
server.port=34256
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
ARG PORT=34256
MAINTAINER me
EXPOSE ${PORT}
COPY ./springdemo-*.jar ./springdemo-*.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","springdemo-*.jar"]
```

Comment: did you verify that the container is up and running and that your application is up?

Comment: Yes, everything is up and running.

Comment: Can you try `docker run -p 34256:34256 -d --network=host --name java-container java-image` and test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `--network=host` to the run arguments.

`docker run -p 34256:34256 -d --network=host --name java-container java-image`

Thanks @Lakshitha Wisumperuma